# Trouble with SharedPreferences conflicting during app operation and then disappearing entirely after an app force close/reboot of device

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

As the title suggest my problem is that some SharedPreferences I'm using are conflicting while the app operates, for example they seem to just be over writing each overs values, and not using their 'key'.

Additionally once the application closes fully, force close/reboot, the file is lost completely.

Logcat shows these possible hints, but I can't for the life of me get anything to work:

```
07-22 13:28:13.980: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(7905):org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Map value without name attribute: string
and
07-22 13:28:13.980: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(7905):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:113)
```

Here is my code for the SharedPrefs:

```
public class SharedPrefs 
{
public static String PREF_FILE = "HangedRes";
public static String USERSCORE;
public static String EXTRAWORDS;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static SharedPreferences settings;
static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static String getStringPreference(Context context, String key) 
{
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    editor = settings.edit();

    String result = settings.getString(key, null);

    return result;
}

public static void setStringPreference(Context context, String key, String value) 
{
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    //editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

/*
public static boolean getBooleanPreference(Context context, String key) {
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    boolean result = settings.getBoolean(key, false);
    return result;
}

public static void setBooleanPreference(Context context, String key, boolean value) 
{
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
*/


}
```

Here is how I am calling those methods in my main code:

```
 // Get current user points and display //////////////////////////
    userScore = SharedPrefs.getStringPreference(this, SharedPrefs.USERSCORE);

    //Check if things are unlocked
    ownWords = SharedPrefs.getStringPreference(this, SharedPrefs.EXTRAWORDS);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your values have plain text? or it has some special `characters`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the values are all plain text and no special characters are used. It's odd almost as if it's not caring about the actual key.

Comment: your code seams perfect..but make one thing sure that before accessing the values, you are setting them..I mean before calling `userScore = SharedPrefs.getStringPreference(this, SharedPrefs.USERSCORE);` you must have set the vale for the key `USERSCORE`.

Comment: Thanks, by ensuring USERSCORE and such are set before I call get on them this has made the data persistent now throughout application closes and re-opening, the values are still clashing however, really odd behaviour.

Comment: your code force me to test it.. why it is not working....:)

Comment: Ok I've managed to solve both issues, thanks to M Mohsin Naeem for your advice. 
First problem is solved by ensuring values are set to the variables:

    public static String USERSCORE ="0";
    public static String EXTRAWORDS ="false";

This solves the non-persistent storage problem.

Next problem is solved by adding a clear in the get statement as follows:

  editor = settings.edit();
  
  String result = settings.getString(key, null);
  editor.clear();
  return result;

Sorry that it is in a comment, as I am a new user I cannot answer my own question for a few hours.

Comment: oh wait why you call `editor.clear()` no need of this..and one more thing use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` instead of `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` read the doc for reference

Comment: Thanks I only changed to world readable on an off chance that was causing the errors so I've since changed that back to private, and the editor.clear() fixed the problem of loading the wrong values, while it shouldn't be needed it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh!

```
public static String USERSCORE;
public static String EXTRAWORDS;
```

where you initialized these keys..?? :)

make it like this

```
public static String USERSCORE="USERSCORE";
public static String EXTRAWORDS="EXTRAWORDS";`
```