# SharedPreferences strange warning

Tags: android

I use SharedPreferences and sometimes I got this warning in logcat:

```
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824): getSharedPreferences
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Map value without name attribute: string
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml(XmlUtils.java:568)
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:821)
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:755)
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:494)
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:113)
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
08-27 11:46:55.453: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(21824):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:87)
```

It is working on most cases but testers said sometimes they got problem with it. Sometimes the loading back simply not works.
This is my `SharedPreffer` Class:

```
public class SharedPreffer {

    String PREF_FILE_NAME = "saveFile";

    public SharedPreffer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    Context context;
    public static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "";

    public void savePreferences(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, Integer.toString(value));
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void savePreferences(String key, Boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, Boolean.toString(value));
        editor.commit();
    }


    public String loadPreferences(String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);

        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, DEFAULT_VALUE);

    }

}
```

Can anybody pass me some tips about this ?

Comment: `Sometimes they got problem with it` is a very good description of the issue. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to write a null reference name, "Map value without name attribute"

Comment: Did you checked these two links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368442/android-getsharedpreferences-error-map-value-without-name-attribute-boolean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601109/trouble-with-sharedpreferences-conflicting-during-app-operation-and-then-disappe

Answer (score 3):

`Map value without name attribute: string` suggests that your `String key` is null or empty.

Check that case in the beginning of your methods and throw exception if something is wrong, you will see from where you are passing such invalid keys:

```
if (key == null || key.equals("")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key can't be null or empty string");
```

Comment: And what if i would like to definetly use "" empty string on default load back ? When there was not stored value at all.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi That's fine, because value can be "". Key can't.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Same Warning many times.

Whenever i use shared preference. Later i noticed that this warning will be shown whenever the app crashes with any runtime exceptions. And restarting the Previous Activity Where you are using Shared Preference to get the preference values. Then i [Googled](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=when%20app%20crashes%20what%20happen%20to%20shared%20preference%20data%20android) it and got this Result from this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4808934/2811956)